# How set orientation in Xcode7 for a specific storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

Hi I am new to Xcode7 and swift2.  I came from android dev background and in android when you declare an activity in the manifest file you can set its orientation limits for each activity (Portrait, Landscape).  What is Xcode7 easiest way of setting orientation restrictions for each storyboard UIview/scene?

Comment: select scene from storyboard and on right side go to attribute inspector and second field in that orientation change that to landscape or portrait which one you want.

Comment: if you want whole application in landscape or portrait mode then click on project and in general tab select that from deployment info.

Answer (score 1):

You can set orientation in two way.

One is, you can set orientation from **Attribute inspector**

[image]

And Second is, You can set it from .plist file.

Add below key in plist file:-

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
```

**Alternate of .plist**

[image: alternative of .plist file]

Hope this will help you.

Thank you.